# SQL taking images is very slow

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, image

I write images to a SQL Server database every minute and then I read those images every minute by client application.

This is a code how I put image into database:

```
PictureBox1.Image.Save(mstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
arrimage = mstream.GetBuffer()

drNowyWiersz3 = m_tabeladanych3.NewRow()
drNowyWiersz3("Id") = k
drNowyWiersz3("bitmap") = arrimage

m_tabeladanych3.Rows.Add(drNowyWiersz3)
drNowyWiersz3 = Nothing
```

`drNowyWiersz3` is datatable new row.

`m_tabeladanych3` is the datatable.

I have 6 images like that (every around 8kb). Taking those images takes sometimes 1 minute (!) especially when I'm connected by Wi-Fi and it makes application errors.

Situation is much better when imageformat is .jpeg but the image is blurry then.

How to improve the process?

edit:

This is the code which I use to read the image, maybe here is the problem?

```
Dim lb2() As Byte = m_tabeladanych3.Rows(1)("bitmap")
Dim lstr2 As New System.IO.MemoryStream(lb2)
PictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(lstr2)
lstr2.Close()
```

Comment: Consider using `arrimage = mstream.ToArray()` instead of `arrimage = mstream.GetBuffer()`.  This way you are only storing the image data and instead of the entire buffer that includes unused bytes.

Comment: I'll try to change this in my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `.jpeg` is performing better than `.bmp` is because the first is a compressed file format where as the second is not.

To improve your setup I would do the following:

1. Compress an image before saving it in the database
2. Have the client retrieve the compressed file, decompress it client-side and display
   it

As an example I used the standard libraries:

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
```

Which enables you to do something like this:

```
private void compressButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Test image to compress:
    FileInfo imageInfo = new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\test.bmp");

    // Compress image
    using (FileStream imageToCompress = imageInfo.OpenRead())
    using (FileStream gzippedImage = File.Create(imageInfo.FullName + ".gz"))
    using (GZipStream gZipStream = new GZipStream(gzippedImage, CompressionMode.Compress))
        imageToCompress.CopyTo(gZipStream);

    Console.WriteLine("Test image compressed using Gzip...");

    // Delete original image
    File.Delete(imageInfo.FullName);
}
private void decompressButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Test image to decompress:
    FileInfo imageInfo = new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\test.bmp.gz");

    // Decompress image
    using (FileStream imageToDecompress = imageInfo.OpenRead())
    using (FileStream decompressedImage = File.Create(imageInfo.FullName.Replace(".gz", ""))) // There are a million other ways to do this, but hey ...
    using (GZipStream gZipStream = new GZipStream(imageToDecompress, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        gZipStream.CopyTo(decompressedImage);

    Console.WriteLine("Gzipped test image decompressed...");

    // Delete gzip
    File.Delete(imageInfo.FullName);
}
```

On top of using compressed data in this case you could also add more resilience to your client-server connections by using asynchronous streams when reading/writing (i.e. use `Stream.ReadAsync` and `Stream.WriteAsync` or similar patterns).